# Error 404 (Not Found)!

Tags: url, ip-address, blogger

My website is www.sbsangpi.com and I checked the IP address of my website is (173.194.72.121). 
Whenever I browse 173.194.72.121, I got message "ERROR 404(Not Found)!!!" 
I use blogger and redirected my blogspot.com to .com. I have tried adding one as my subdomain but still nothing affected! I can access my website using www.sbsangpi.com but not with IP.

How Can I redirect 173.194.72.121 to my home page www.sbsangpi.com?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: using IP to access website, sometime can bypass blocked by character in Proxy.

Comment: Do you actually own that IP? If you're on a shared hosting account, you're going to be *sharing* it with several other people. If for some reason you need to be accessing your site by IP, you'll need to buy a dedicated one from your host. (Assuming they offer the service.)

Comment: yes! I have brought www.sbsangpi.com from Godaddy through Google.com and I can created subdomain upto 100 or somethings.

Comment: You own the domain, but do you own the IP address?

Comment: isn't it the another way of calling something in two (number or letter)

Comment: You've *bought* (not brought) the domain name, which resolves to that IP address.  However there may be other domain names that also resolve to that IP addres, and the server will use the domain requested to serve the right site.  Therefore going in by IP address will not work unless specifically configured to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact your webhost. Unless you've set up your own server and are using that, you have to ask your webhost to redirect the IP for you.

In which, as @Su' said, you'll have to get your own dedicated IP (Which is probably going to cost more). IPs and URLs aren't synonymous. They are two different entities that are tied together using a server configuration (an A Record).

**Situation a):** *You don't own the IP*

Use the contact page on GoDaddy to get customer service and request a dedicated IP (it will cost extra), then have the IP attached to your domain name.

**Situation b):** *You do own the IP*

Use the contact page on GoDaddy to get customer service and request that your IP be attached to your domain.

---

There aren't a whole lot of situations to do this, most people are used to and prefer a domain over an IP. Unless you're creating some kind of external webapp, the extra cost and effort to do this isn't worth it. In the modern world, IP addresses come and go.